# Advanced .htaccess URL Redirect/Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am not very experienced with .htaccess files and editing, could you guys please help me with this?

I need to redirect all url's that start with

```
mydomain.com/shop/category/EXAMPLE-CATEGORY-NAME
```

to this:

```
mydomain.com/shop-products/EXAMPLE-CATEGORY-NAME
```

For example, if I set the rule on `'www.blahblah.com'`, then it should redirect `http://www.blahblah.com/shop/category/thisisanexample/`

to

`http://www.blahblah.com/shop-products/thisisanexample/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/category/(.*)$ /shop-products/$1
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?shop/category/(.*)$ /shop-products/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want the redirect the browser (i.e. change the URL in the browser's address bar), remove the `R=301` flag from the brackets so it's just `[L]`, then going to `http://www.blahblah.com/shop/category/thisisanexample/` will make it so the browser's address bar is unchanged but gets served the content at `/shop-products/thisisanexample/`.

Comment: First one worked great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/shop-products/(.*)$ /shop/category/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This one didn't work - not sure why though.